# Icon sizes for UWP apps (Universal Windows Platform, AppX)

Tags: uwp, electron, windows-10-universal, electron-builder, appx

I'd like to understand the necessary **icon** and **logo** sizes for UWP apps (AppX).

According to documentation there are several images https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/app-icons-and-logos

- *SmallTile.png* - I've no idea what size it should be.
- *Square150x150Logo.png* - 150 x 150 px? Or maybe 300 x 300 px?
- *Wide310x150Logo.png* - ?
- *LargeTile.png* - no idea.
- *Square44x44Logo.png* - 44 x 44 px?
- *SplashScreen.png* - any idea?
- *BadgeLogo.png* - do you know?
- *StoreLogo.png* - what about store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In UWP, a variety of icons with different sizes will be generated to adapt to different usage environments.

In `Package.appxmanifest` of Visual Studio, there are definitions for the size of the picture type you mentioned. (Details can be found in `Package.appxmanifest/Visual Assets`)

Here is an examples:

**SmallTile** (5 sizes, units are pixels)

- 284x284 (Recommend)
- 142x142 (Recommend)
- 71x71 (Recommend)
- 107x107
- 89x89

**LargeTile**

- 1240x1240 (Recommend)
- 620x620 (Recommend)
- 310x310 (Recommend)
- 465x465
- 388x388

The picture with the {number}x{number} in the picture name means pixels, and the {scale-number} means the zoom ratio.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Maximum sizes of images for UWP:

- StoreLogo.png — 200x200 (original: 50x50)
- Square150x150Logo.png — 600x600 (original: 150x150)
- Square44x44Logo.png — 256x256 (original: 44x44 [more info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/app-icons-and-logos#more-about-app-icon-assets))
- Wide310x150Logo.png — 1240x600 (original: 310x150)
- SmallTile.png (Square71x71Logo) — 284x284 (original: 71x71)
- LargeTile.png (Square310x310Logo) — 1240x1240 (original: 310x310)
- SplashScreen — 2480x1200 (original: 620x300 [more info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/splash-screens))

---

Documentation:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/app-icons-and-logos
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/tailor-resources-lang-scale-contrast
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/splash-screens
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/badges